# At what point is a (disk-based) table removed from memory after data is read from it?

Tags: sql-server, memory, table, buffer-pool

Are (disk-based, so no Hekaton) tables persisted in memory for longer than the lifespan of the query that is reading data from them?

If so, what determines how long they stay in memory for?

Is there a way to manage how long they persist in memory for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to force an index to stay in memory with SQL Server 2008?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13140/is-there-a-way-to-force-an-index-to-stay-in-memory-with-sql-server-2008)

Comment: You could so a SELECT * FROM MyTable periodically or shortly before the data is needed by the query.  This is certainly a hack, and possibly a waste of resources, but in certain circumstances it might be rational.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a complicated topic, much of which is covered in [this Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15).

To answer a couple of points:

> Are (disk-based, so no Hekaton) tables persisted in memory for longer than the lifespan of the query that is reading data from them?

Sort of.  Entire tables aren't necessarily persisted in memory.  Individual *pages* from a table or index are stored in memory - it could be the entire table, or just a portion of it.

> If so, what determines how long they stay in memory for?

You'll have to reference the article I linked to, but lots of things can cause "memory pressure" which will lead to data pages being "evicted" from the cache.

Things like the amount of memory available to SQL Server, other data and index pages being pulled into memory, other SQL Server data caches needing memory, "external" pressure from the OS and other processes on the box, etc can all result in pages being kicked out of cache.

SQL Server uses a "least recently used" cache, so the least recently referenced pages will generally get kicked out first.

> Is there a way to manage how long they persist in memory for?

Only by making sure SQL Server has enough memory to keep the pages in the buffer pool, and making sure other processes don't put pressure on SQL Server.

One thing that can help prevent the OS from taking memory back from SQL Server is turning on the Lock Pages in Memory (LPIM) feature.

---

As a historical note, `DBCC PINTABLE` used to work for keeping a table in memory, however, it was [deprecated as of SQL Server 2005](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/dbcc-pintable/) (and now does nothing at all).